# Cannot catch NoSuchAlertError coming from Protractor when using async/await

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm following the new changes happening to Selenium (and Protractor) using the docs here: [async-wait.md](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/async-await.md)

So the scenario is that I might have an alert or not so I try and catch NoSuchAlertError. The problem is that the catch is being ignored.

```
this.closeAlert = async function (acceptAlert) {
    try {
        var alert = await browser.driver.switchTo().alert();

        if (acceptAlert) {
            return alert.accept();
        }

        return alert.dismiss();
    } catch (e) {}
};
```

I'm getting

```
Failed: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562713 (dd642283e958a93ebf6891600db055f1f1b4f3b2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
NoSuchAlertError: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562713 (dd642283e958a93ebf6891600db055f1f1b4f3b2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From asynchronous test:
```

Additionally the code works when there is an alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this command isn't awaitable. I tried using your code snippet and intellisense was telling me it didn't have a callable `then` member.

[image]

Here is how I was able to get it to work:

```
var alert = browser.driver.switchTo().alert()
    .catch(e => console.log('caught:', e));
```

As you can see it worked:

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround, works for me. I thought AlertPromise implements webdriver's IThenable interface so this still has some mystery.

Comment: Agreed. Really not sure why it doesn't work but at least there is a workaround.